# Zend get model id from uri

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I'm getting trying to get familiar with Zend and have a question that's probably a no-brainer, but so far haven't been able to find the answer via Google or SO.

What is the default method of passing a model's ID via the URI. I've tried

```
http://myurl/controller/edit/1
```

where 1 is the corresponding primary key in the database, but am unable to get the id in the editAction() method with

```
$request = $this->getRequest();    
$id = $request->getParam('id');`
```

I'm guessing there's a simple configuration item I'm missing. Could someone kindly point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default routes in ZF look like

```
[/<module>]/<controller>/<action>/<param1>/<value1>/<param2>/<value2>
```

So, in your example, you'd want something like:

```
/controller/edit/id/1
```

If you want to do-away with the /id/ bit, you'll need to define a custom route.